# Javascript referenced value not updated?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I basically have an object, but this object will only be filled after user input. But the other classes are using this object also. But then after I fill the object with the real object, it doesn't get updated in the other classes.

Example :

```
var x = {
  text: null
}
var y = {
  text: x.text
}

x.text = 'trlalala';

console.log(y.text);
console.log(x.text);
```

but when I run it, y.text will print out null. But the value should be updated already. One of my friend told me it's because y.text copy the structure of x.text instead of the reference. Been stuck for a while. :\

Any input will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text: x.text` looks at the value of `x.text` (a reference to `null`) and sets `y.text` to that.

When you say `x.text = 'trlalala'`, then you change the value of `x.text` (so it is a reference to the immutable string `'trlalala'`) but the value of `y.text` remains a reference to `null`.

You would need an intermediate object that you get a reference to if you want to share data like that. (Since then you would be dealing with a reference to an object)

```
var x = {
  data: { text: null }
};
var y = {
  data: x.data
};

x.data.text = 'trlalala';

console.log(y.data.text);
console.log(x.data.text);
```

Comment: it works. thanks. the only problem is that now every time I want to call the variable, I need to write y.data.text, which is a bit long. I shortened it using z = y.data though, but it's still z.data, but well I think it's the best it can get.

Answer (score 2):

When you define `y`, you're defining a property (i.e. a constant value) rather than a method.  And you define the value of `text` to be `x.text` - which means at *definition time*, the value of `x.text` is looked up and used as the (constant) value of `y.text`.

If you want changes in `x.text` to be reflected in `y`, then you can define `y.text` to be a *function*, so that this value is looked up on-demand every time that the method is called.  This might look something like this:

```
var y = {
   text: function() {
      return x.text;
   }
};
```

Now whenever you update `x.text`, subsequent calls to `y.text()` will yield the new value.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript a string is a [primitive value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Glossary#primitive), which can not be referenced (directly), but is just copied like in your case.

So your friend is right: With the command `text: x.text` just the current value of `x.text` is copied, which here is `null.

The reassignment of `x.text` has no influence on `y.text` as this is just a copy and no reference!